# Scheme How to write list of lists into CSV file

Tags: list, csv, scheme, racket

as title, I have a list of lists

```
'((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))
```

And I follow the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/file-ports.html) to come up with this

```
(define (write-to-a-file l path)
  (call-with-output-file path
    (lambda (output-port)
      (write l output-port))
    #:exists 'replace
    #:mode 'binary))
```

It helps write the list to csv file. However, the csv content is not separated, it seems like the entire list was dumped into the file (i.e, ((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)), not 1 2 (two cells) 3 4 (two cells) etc)
Is there any approach that can write a list of lists into csv in Scheme , like Python ?

Comment: What is`(two cells)`? Can you give an example of the intended data in the CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question is for writing text to a file, nothing in it is specific for writing a CSV file. You'd need to parse the list contents, writing each sublist in a different line, separating the elements with commas.

But we don't need to reinvent the wheel, in Racket just install the [`csv-writing`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/csv-writing) package - in case you can't find it, the `raco` command is in the `bin` folder where you installed Racket:

```
raco pkg install csv-writing
```

Now we can use it:

```
(require csv-writing)

(define (write-to-a-file lst path)
  (call-with-output-file path
    (lambda (output-port)
      (display-table lst output-port))
    #:exists 'replace))
```

Call your procedure like this:

```
(define lst '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
(write-to-a-file lst "/path/to/file.csv")
```

The contents of `file.csv` will be:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```